# Issue with jQuery Upload

Tags: php, jquery

A very amazing user from my last question gave me a piece of code that seemed to work on his end... Not so much on mine though.

Below is the code:

```
$json = array('code' => 200, 'msg' => "Avatar uploaded!");

//if a file was submitted
if($_FILES)
{
    try
    {
        $filename = md5(time() . rand(0, 1000));
        $result = $bulletproof->fileTypes(["png", "jpeg"])
                ->uploadDir("uploads")
                ->limitSize(["min" => 1000, "max" => 300000])
                ->shrink(["height" => 96, "width" => 96])
                ->upload($_FILES['image_file'], $filename);          
       print_r(json_encode($json));        
    } 
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $json['code'] = 500;
        $json['msg'] = $e->getMessage();
        print_r(json_encode($json));
    }
}
else
{
    //no file was submitted
    //send back a 500 error code and a error message
    $json['code'] = 500;
    $json['msg'] = "You must select a file";
    print_r(json_encode($json));
}
```

So, when I submit the data with an image, it then sends the POST request but it returns a 500 internal server error. Anyone have an idea why?

Please have a look at the link below:

http://i.gyazo.com/6145dff8581633318c69ea3713b1112e.png

Comment: What is the JSON response?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error. It doesn't display a response.

Comment: Open the PHP page directly in your browser, do you get error message?

Comment: I followed the conversation on your other question and tried logging in / submitting a file and see the same problem you describe.  I notice the response has no message, so assume that it's the `try...catch` that's generating the 500, not the `else`.  For an experiment, I tried uploading an oversized file to see whether `LimitSize` would throw an error, but still got an empty error response.  Indicates to me that it's the early lines that are failing. Does `uploads` directory exist? Have you checked that `$filename` looks as you expect?

Comment: @blablabla: When I go to the PHP directly it gives me the 500 Internal Server error saying I haven't submitted a file.

@J Richard Snape: Alright I'll look into it later tody and reply back on it.

Comment: @J Richard Snape, I still get the same issue (500 internal server).

Comment: This is my code now http://i.gyazo.com/26a06861c404b8dd63251e7c772d711e.png | I removed EVERYTHING and it's just that now, and I STILL get the 500 internal server error.

Comment: Bumping this topic, still can't solve it.